# Automate Free Hotspot Login

Tags: macos, bash, automation, macros, keyboard-input

A hotspot in my area requires authentication every hour. I am trying to automate the process so that it requires no user input. I am using OS X for this. I have a bash script that does this:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 up
networksetup -setairportnetwork en1 [networkssid]
open [hotspotlogin]
```

I need something that does this:

1. Check the URL to make sure the page has loaded
2. Change a dropdown entry
3. Fill in 2 text fields
4. Check a checkbox
5. Press the 'go' button
6. Close the window

This could also be automated by keyboard presses, but I don't know a way to do that in bash script.

Comment: First try to make it work with additional keypresses. Put it in a file, make the file executable and try again. When that works, try using a scheduler.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/198967/371118 has some good pointers